# Read network stream from multiple devices

Tags: c#, asynchronous, network-programming

I have an industrial scale that transmits the current weight across the network continuously. I wrote a C# application to read this data stream. The only problem is that only one copy of the application on only one device can read the data coming from the scale. I need to be able to read the data from the scale from multiple devices simultaneously. Does anyone have ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have one process continuously read the devices. Publish the data to a database. Make all the other interested processes read from the database.

You also can do it without a database in memory. The device reader can expose a webservice to other interested processes.

Comment: I actually considered the webservice idea. I'm just not sure how to go about it. Can you write an application that is both a client and a server?

Comment: Sure. Create a new ASP.NET WCF project. Callers can call you over WCF. You can call others any way you like, e.g. HttpWebRequest or Socket.